# find no req.body usando populate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express.js, mongoose

Controller

```
async index(req, res) {
        const avali = await Avaliacao.find(req.body)
        .populate('Time').exec((time, err) => {
            console.log(`Para retorna tudo ${time}`)
        })

    return res.send(avali)
},
```

Model

```
const AvaliacaoShema = new Schema({
responsavel: {
    type: String
},
time: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Time',
}]
})
module.exports = model('Avaliacao', AvaliacaoShema)
```

Estou tentando da um req.body, mas no campo time não retorna o valor do objeto com o esperado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente realizar os seguintes ajustes:

1. Verifique se o parâmetro para a busca da Avaliacao está retornando corretamente;
2. coloque o valor do path do populate, exatamente igual ('time') ao atributo no schema do mongoose.
3. Caso ainda não funcione, envie mais detalhes sobre o parâmetro que está enviando através do body, sobre qual a finalidada e etc.

   ```
   async index(req, res, next) {
   let param = { responsavel: req.body.responsavel }
   const avali = await Avaliacao.find(param)
     .populate({ path: 'time' })
     .exec()
     .then(time => {
       console.log("Para retorna tudo" + time)
     })
   res.send(avali)}
   ```